# Does IO prioritise by the very nature of renicing a task?

Tags: linux, kernel, io, priority, nice

The CFQ IO scheduler supports priorities though I am not sure that Deadline does (I believe not). The premise is that when I renice a task it gets a larger share of CPU under the Completely Fair Scheduler. Since this task is likely to run more often it would call for IO more often as well when needed, correct?

I am wondering if even though the IO scheduler does not support priorities that the task would get more/less IO when reniced? Or is the disk/memory management completely separate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disk and memory scheduling are entirely different. In the absence of an IO priority scheduler, IO will be handled on a first come first served basis.  If the system is IO bound, then all processes run in a more or less round robin basis until all are waiting for I/O.  The nice priority of a process will have little impact on its scheduling frequency.

Recent versions of Linux have added an `ionice` facility.  The idle priority is intended to prevent IO degradation which may occur when the heads are moved to a different area of the disk delaying writes for other processes.

Renicing an I/O bound process is unlikely to significantly slow its I/O rate unless the load average exceeds the number of CPUs.  If unused CPU cycles are available, the process will likely be scheduled frequently enough to keep its I/O rate close to what it would be at a regular priority.

Recent Linux kernels will modify the IO priority of reniced process which have not had an IO priority set.  The 40 CPU priority levels are mapped to 8 IO priority levels, so a significant nice change may be required to change the IO priority.

Having a significant number of CPU bound processes running at or above the I/O bound processes priority may slow its I/O rate.  The process will still get time slices resulting in I/O occurring.